# How do you sign out a user, without forcing the user to press a button in Blazor?

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, azure-ad-b2c, .net-5

I have this very annoying issue in Blazor.

I'm using Azure AD B2C to authenticate users in my web app.

I have a scenario, where I want to check if the user is authenticated, and if yes, the user should be signed out.

It seems like sign out requests need to be peformed within the  context inside an . Otherwise the user will be able to sign in again without using credentials.

If I use the following everything works:

```
<AuthorizeView>
<Authorized>
    <Button @onclick="BeginSignout"></Button>
</Authorized>
<NotAuthorized>
   ....
</NotAuthorized>
```

Notice the button, that the user is forced to click on. No problem at all.

However if I do like this:

```
<AuthorizeView>
<Authorized>
    <Signout/>
</Authorized>
<NotAuthorized>
   ....
</NotAuthorized>
```

Which executes the following code inside the Signout component, it DOESN'T WORK and the user is still signed in:

```
    protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await base.OnInitializedAsync();

        await BeginSignout();
    }
```

There's simply not enough documentation on this issue, and seems like my use-case is very uncommon apperently and therefore I haven't been able to figure this out.

I've also tried with an invisible DIV that is supposed to execute "BeginSignout" when loaded, but the @onload event doesn't work.

BeginSignout is calling the following code:

```
    public async Task SignOut(string? redirectUri = null)
    {
        if(redirectUri == null)
        {
            redirectUri = Uri.EscapeDataString(this.navigationManager.Uri);
        }

        await this.signOutManager.SetSignOutState();
        this.navigationManager.NavigateTo($"authentication/logout?returnUrl={redirectUri}");

    }
```

I'm lost, and this should've been a simple task that is just taking all of my time.

Comment: `Sign out` means terminating the user's server session. On the client side `sign out` has no meaning, not just for Blazor but all SPAs. Someone could modify the application through the JavaScript console and replace functions, so sessions are simply *not* controlled by the client

Comment: Yes I know that, but in this case it doesn't really affect the security if someone did that. It's just a matter of creating the correct userflow

Comment: You didn't even mention if it's Blazor Server or WASM. In both cases the only meaningful signout is on the server. You can make the client behave as if it wasn't logged in (eg by clearing cookies and storage), but that wouldn't change the actual behavior. And since the code for `BeginSignout` is missing, we can't guess what is going on. Or what you even mean by `SignOut`

Comment: Since you use AD-B2C you could conceivable call AD to end the session.

Comment: Aready did that, but didn't help at all. I called this endpoint: https://{tenant}.b2clogin.com/{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_login/oauth2/v2.0/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fjwt.ms%2F&client-request-id=xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxx

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's inside your BeginSignout method (please add your method code to the question) but it's better to add this kind of signout to the AfterRender method.

If your authentication mode is based on cookie you need to call a cshtml method because wasm pages cannot set cookies.

Comment: I added the code as you requested. And no I think its just JwtBearerDefaults